# how to query firebase database and put them on Map

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase database and it has locations such as

- locations

  - loc 1

    - location name1
    - location coordinats1
  - loc 2

    - location name2
    - location coordinats2
  - loc 3

    - location name3
    - location coordinats3

how can put them on google maps with coordiants and on names. I am not clear how can query each "locs" and equalize them to a map point.

like this

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

Comment: check out the answer I gave to this question, it should point you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39517835/how-to-use-firebase-realtime-database-for-android-google-map-app?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

try this

`mRef.child("locations").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    MyObject obj = snapshot.getValue(MyObject.class);
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(obj.coordinats()).title(obj.getname()));
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });`